# How to configure VS Code intellisense to support custom class pattern (`class: " "` rather than just `class= " "`)?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, erb

I'm working on Rails's `html.erb` file, after a lot of fiddling I'm finally figured out how to make intellisense autosuggestion works. The problem is it currently works with this `class = ""` pattern
[image: works with class = "" pattern]

but not `class: ""` pattern
[image: not work with class: "" pattern, no bootstrap class suggested]
which is the way to define class in ERB `<% %>` tag

I'm currently using [SCSS Everywhere](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gencer.html-slim-scss-css-class-completion) extension and have tried [HTML CSS Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css). They behaved the same.

So TLDR;

Want intellisense to work on `class: "..."` pattern but seems to only work on `class="..."` pattern. Is there a setting ( global/extension level, global level preferred) to define this, or are there an already well-known fix I'm not aware of?